# What is the surface feature of the mesas in the Noctis Labyrinthus on Mars?

Tags: mars, surface

Caveat-my knowledge of geology is limited.

Is it known what is the surface like on the [larger mesas in the Noctis Labyrinthus](https://www.geo.fu-berlin.de/en/geol/fachrichtungen/planet/press/archiv2016/noctis_labyrinthus1/index.html)?  I trust the very smooth looking surface on this mesa is a product of low image resolution and not proof it is perfectly smooth.

[image]

This smaller mesa

[image]

is described as [clusters of boulders and sand dunes](https://www.nasa.gov/image-feature/jpl/pia21585/a-mesa-in-noctis-labyrinthus) on its surface. Do the larger mesas have these features?  Something like this,
[image]

Here are different surfaces from images taken by the Mars rovers. Is it known if the larger mesas have surfaces like any of these?

[image]

No dunes or clusters of large boulders.

[image]

Granted this is not entirely flat, but in the foreground it looks to my laymen's eye as surface bedrock with little sand.

[image]
Or generally flat rocks broken up and separate, with sand in between the rocks?

Comment: you could contrast grayscale/and texture, images in near area o same scale in gray, and use [google mars](https://www.google.com/mars/) and use "type" as description surface, for recreation of surface

Comment: I don't understand.